# How to show search and clear icon into textbox at right end in winforms in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I wanted to show my search and clear(cross mark) icon into textbox that i had designed to search my treeview. When user enter into textbox and writes some text into it i want my cross icon to be visible and when nothing is written inside of it i wanted to show search icon.

What i have done so far is something like this.[image]

but i wanted it to be like this when nothing entered.[image]

and when text is entered i wanted to be like this -> [image]

also when user clicks cross mark i wanted textbox to get empty.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can live with the icon sitting **above** the text you can do this:

Add a `Panel IconPanel` and **nest** it in the `TextBox textBox1`:

```
Panel IconPanel = new Panel();
IconPanel.Parent = textBox1;
IconPanel.Size = new Size(32, textBox1.ClientSize.Height);  // use your numbers!
IconPanel.Location = new Point(textBox1.Width - IconPanel.Width, 0);
IconPanel.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

Add your icons to the project resources and code the `TextChanged` event like this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IconPanel.BackgroundImage = textBox1.Text.Length == 0 ?
              global::yourProjectName.Properties.Resources.searchIcon :
              global::yourProjectName.Properties.Resources.clearIcon;
}
```

Initialize the `IconPanel.BackgroundImage` depending on your intial `Textbox` content!